# Rails 4 has_many syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does anybody know the correct syntax in Rails 4.2 for

```
 has_many :requested_friends, 
          :source => :friend, 
          :through => :friendships where :conditions => "status = requested"
```

In Rails 2.3

I had

```
   has_many :requested_friends,
          :through => :friendships,
          :source => :friend,
          :conditions => "status = 'requested'"
```

Answer (score 2):

The below should work

```
has_many :requested_friends,
          -> { where status: 'requested' },
          :through => :friendships,
          :source => :friend
```

Comment: That gave

/app/models/user.rb:16: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>

So I changed it to

has_many :requested_friends,
          :through => :friendships,
          :source => :friend, => {where status: 'requested'}
Which gave
app/models/user.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected => :source => :friend, => {where status: 'requested'} ^ /app/models/user.rb:15: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end

Comment: The lambda argument needs to come before the options. E.g. `has_many :requested_friends, -> { where....}, :through => ...etc...`

Comment: @gleb Updated the answer

Comment: Update doesn't work because status is a column in the friendship table. It's looking at the user table